# Computing a map in the long exact sequence (sheaf cohomology)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $E \subset \mathbb P^2$ be a curve cut out by a homogeneous polynomial of degree 3. This is an elliptic curve and so $H^0(E, \mathscr O) = H^1(E, \mathscr O) \cong \mathbb C$. Now I want to calculate the cohomology of the sheaf $\mathscr O_E(p)$, where $p\in E$.

To this end we use the following short exact sequence 
$$ 0 \to I_{\{p\}} \to \mathscr O_E \to S_p \to 0, $$

where $I$ and $S$ are the ideal sheaf and skyscraper sheaf at $p$. As $I_{\{p\}} \cong \mathscr O_E(-p)$, tensoring the sequence with $\mathscr O_E(p)$ gives

$$ 0 \to \mathscr O \to \mathscr O(p) \to S_p \to 0$$

which induces the following long exact sequence:

$$ 0 \to H^0(\mathscr O) \to H^0(\mathscr O(p)) \overset{g}{\to} \mathbb C \to H^1(\mathscr O) \to H^1 (\mathscr O(p)) \to 0 \to 0 \to \cdots$$

Now I want to show that $g$ is zero. This should be true as we know $H^1(\mathscr O(p)) = \{0\}$, so $\mathbb C \to H^1(\mathscr O_E)$ is an isomorphism. But I have had a hard time showing that this is true (Indeed, I do not want to use $H^1(\mathscr O(p)) = \{0\}$ here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $\dim H^0(\mathscr O_E(p))=1$. Exactness says $\ker g=\textrm{im } (H^0(\mathscr O_E)\to H^0(\mathscr O_E(p)))=H^0(\mathscr O_E(p))$.

Comment: How do we know that dim$H^0(\mathscr O_E(p)) = 1$?

Comment: Every divisor $D>0$ on $E$ has $h^0(\mathscr O_E(D))=\deg D$, by Riemann-Roch. Well, one uses $h^1(\mathscr O_E(D))=0$, which is true since $\deg D>\deg K_E=0$.